Geometry Nodes cube - texture
I would greatly appreciate your help, as I seem to be stuck.
I have generated a cube using Geometry Nodes, which consists of three smaller cubes of different sizes. Everything is animated and forms one large object. I would like each face of the large cube to have a texture applied in the form of an image.
I would be grateful for any help, even a small hint on how to approach this.

I'd make seams to create UV islands. Keep track of which islands are facing out (special attention to corner cubes). Based on the position and size of each cube, I'd map the UV vector with geometry nodes using "scale = proportional (or inverse) to the little cube size" and "position = proportional (positive or negative) to the size of the big cube.

It would help a lot to see your blend file, consider uploading it here : https://blend-exchange.com/

Of course, here is the file:


The way I would do it is to calculate in shader, based on position and scale of the cube how to map range the UVMap this way you don't even need to realize instances and you get a full unwrap all around the sub-cube.
